# How to cache data in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have a service "OneTimeService" that has a "init" method.

```
 // Within OneTimeService code
var this = self;
this.init = function() {
 return $http..... function(data) {
     self.data = data
 }
}
```

Inside of each of my controllers that are associated with my routes, I have a :
     // Within some controller code
    OneTimeService.init().then(data) {
    $scope.somevariable = data.someattribute;
    // do other stuff
    }

The problem I have is, I have 10 different "routes". Each of them has the:

```
 // Within every controller (assuming each route I have uses a different controller) code but injects the OneTimeService.
OneTimeService.init().then(data) {
$scope.somevariable = data.someattribute;
// do other stuff
}
```

Everytime I call "init()", it performs an $http request, when in actuality, all I want is to be able to call it ONE TIME EVER in my application $http request, then use the cached variable "self.data" from the service. The reason why I like the .then is it guarantees that I have "self.data" set within the OneTimeService prior to doing anything else. Are there alternatives?

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd cache the data on the OneTimeService where I check if the data already exists (from previous call) or not, and using a promise like the $q service:

1- If the data NOT exists, I'll let the $http service call the server to retrieve the data and then I can cache it in a variable inside the service.

2- If the data does exist, resolve the promise straight away using the cached data and return.

So something like this :

```
// in OneTimeService code

var _cachedData = null;

this.init = function() {
    var def = $q.defer();

    // check if _cachedData was already cached
    if(_cachedData){
        def.resolve(_cachedData);        
    }

    // call the server for the first and only time
    $http.get(url).then(function(data) {
        // cache the data
        _cachedData = data;
        def.resolve(_cachedData);
    }, function(err){
        def.reject(err);
    });
    return def.promise;
}
```

Hope this helps.